# Почему у классов часть методов скрыта?

Tags: python, классы, методы

Приветстсвую! Недавно узнал, что есть очень полезный метод класса `__subclasses__`, который выдаёт список всех подклассов. Но к своему удивлению, я не обнаружил его в общем списке методов класса...

```
class A:
    pass

print(dir(A))
```

Вывод: `['__class__', '__delattr__', '__dict__', '__dir__', '__doc__', '__eq__', '__format__', '__ge__', '__getattribute__', '__gt__', '__hash__', '__init__', '__init_subclass__', '__le__', '__lt__', '__module__', '__ne__', '__new__', '__reduce__', '__reduce_ex__', '__repr__', '__setattr__', '__sizeof__', '__str__', '__subclasshook__', '__weakref__']`

Если далее обратиться к методу:

```
print(A.__subclasses__())
```

Выведется: `[]`
Вопрос: почему рабочего и очень полезного метода `__subclasses__` нет в списке всех методов класса? Почему это так? Что особенного в этом методе? Сколько ещё полезных методов скрыты от глаз программистов? Где их можно посмотреть?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Метод `__subclasses__` не был создан для непосредственного использования в прикладном коде. Он нужен для некоторых внутренних нужд языка (если подробнее, то для поддержки изменения иерархии классов на уровне C и ускорения разрешения порядка методов). В частности, об этом пишет Тим Петерс: https://mail.python.org/pipermail/python-list/2003-August/210297.html

Поэтому существование этого метода и не афишируется.

На самом деле `dir` не гарантирует того, что вы увидите полный и истинный список методов и атрибутов. Для любого вашего класса можно переопределить специальный метод `__dir__`, и тогда вы сами можете решать, что увидит тот, кто сделает dir() для вашего класса.

Это может быть удобно, например, для классов, у которых набор атрибутов создаётся динамически с помощью `__getattribute__` или `__getattr__`.

Что касается вопроса о том, где можно посмотреть все методы, то это можно сделать, например, тут: https://pythonz.net/references/named/object/